# Where do I register a ValueTransformer in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to use a `ValueTransformer` (né `NSValueTransformer`) in Swift that is being used by the first window that my application opens. Value transformers need to be registered with `ValueTransformer.registerValueTransformer(_:forName:)` before they can be queried by the user interface runtime.

The documentation for `NSValueTransformer` [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/Registration.html) registering value transformers in `+[AppDelegate initialize]`. However, Swift doesn't allow you to override `+initialize`. I tried to register from `applicationWillFinishLaunching(_)` and `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_)`, but they both happen too late and my window doesn't get filled because the runtime can't find the value transformer.

Where should I register my value transformer?

Comment: But certainly you could override your app delegate's `init` function and register them there.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that pretty quickly (and answered myself to that effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you can register your value transformers in the `AppDelegate`. If you want something that closer resembles ObjectiveC's `+initialize` you can use lazy initialization of a class variable. E.g:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    static let doInitialize: Void = {
        // register transformers here
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        AppDelegate.doInitialize
    }
}
```

This pattern should also work for classes other than the `AppDelegate` if you want to keep the transformers things closer to the classes that actually use them.

Answer (score 6):

In AppDelegate you can use a dummy property of type `Void` with a closure. The closure is even executed before `init`

```
private let transformer : Void = {
    let myTransformer = MyValueTransformer()
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(myTransformer, forName:NSValueTransformerName("MyValueTransformer"))
}()
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that I can count on the app delegate class to be `init`ialized early and only once, so I stuck my `ValueTransformer.registerValueTransformer` call in it.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    override init() {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(MyValueTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("MyValueTransformer"))
    }
}
```