# Crash when adopting NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer for a Transformable property

Tags: ios, core-data, ios13, nssecurecoding

In iOS 12 Apple introduced `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` for use on CoreData model entities' Transformable properties. I used to keep the Transformer Name field empty, which implicitly used `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`. This transformer is now deprecated, and keeping the field empty in the future will mean `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` instead.

In iOS 13, if that field is empty, you now get a runtime warning telling you the aforementioned. I couldn't find any documentation on this anywhere, the only reference I got was a WWDC 2018 Core Data Best Practices talk which briefly mentioned what I just said.

Now I have a model with an entity which directly stores `HTTPURLResponse` objects in a Transformable property. It conforms to `NSSecureCoding`, and I checked in runtime that `supportsSecureCoding` is `true`.

Setting `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` for the Transformer Name crashes with this message:

```
Object of class NSHTTPURLResponse is not among allowed top level class list (
    NSArray,
    NSDictionary,
    NSSet,
    NSString,
    NSNumber,
    NSDate,
    NSData,
    NSURL,
    NSUUID,
    NSNull
) with userInfo of (null)
```

So it sounds like Transformable properties can only be of these top level objects.

I tried subclassing the secure transformer and override the `allowedTopLevelClasses` property as suggested by the documentation:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public class NSSecureUnarchiveHTTPURLResponseFromDataTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {

    override public class var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [HTTPURLResponse.self]
    }
}
```

Then I'd imagine I can create a custom transformer name, set it in the model and call `setValueTransformer(_:forName:)` for that name, but I couldn't find API to set the default `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` for my custom name in case I'm on iOS 11.

Keep in mind, I'm using Xcode 11 Beta 5, but this doesn't seem to be related if I am to accept the meaning of the error I'm getting as stated.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but a few years ago Apple did something similar to binary stores. There is a key for the persistent store options dictionary to register other acceptable types: `NSBinaryStoreSecureDecodingClasses`. Maybe that will lead you to the answer.

Comment: Not really an answer but more an observation: from my experience reverse engineering Apple apps, they actually use proto buffs for storing class objects in coredata when they don’t support secure coding. I don’t think even Apple at this point has a solution for what you want seeing as they just went with a different archive method

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this observation to be honest. Keep in mind though, I simply haven't tried making this change until now, but `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` has been available since iOS 12, and they started telling people to switch to it since WWDC 2018 more than a year ago.

Comment: It appears the transformers are compatible. This is from the apple docs on NSKeyedArchive.archivedData `Enabling secure coding doesn’t change the output format of the archive. This means that you can encode archives with secure coding enabled, and decode them later with secure coding disabled.`

Comment: Great find Adam! I was pretty sure they wouldn't be compatible, it's reassuring to know this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a simple template class which makes it easy to create and register a transformer for any class that implements `NSSecureCoding`. It works fine for me in iOS 12 and 13, at least in my simple test using `UIColor` as the transformable attribute.

To use it (using `UIColor` as an example):

```
// Make UIColor adopt ValueTransforming
extension UIColor: ValueTransforming {
  static var valueTransformerName: NSValueTransformerName { 
    .init("UIColorValueTransformer")
  }
}

// Register the transformer somewhere early in app startup.
NSSecureCodingValueTransformer<UIColor>.registerTransformer()
```

The name of the transformer to use in the Core Data model is `UIColorValueTransformer`.

```
import Foundation

public protocol ValueTransforming: NSSecureCoding {
  static var valueTransformerName: NSValueTransformerName { get }
}

public class NSSecureCodingValueTransformer<T: NSSecureCoding & NSObject>: ValueTransformer {
  public override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass { T.self }
  public override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool { true }

  public override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let value = value as? T else { return nil }
    return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: true)
  }

  public override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let data = value as? NSData else { return nil }
    let result = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
      ofClass: T.self,
      from: data as Data
    )
    return result
  }

  /// Registers the transformer by calling `ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(_:forName:)`.
  public static func registerTransformer() {
    let transformer = NSSecureCodingValueTransformer<T>()
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: T.valueTransformerName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Gist here: https://gist.github.com/rudedogdhc/0ae51a8e97a350458386fd914f0f9874

Comment: Would you happen to know why a transformer would work on simulator without issue but crash on the device as soon as it opened? The only way I get it to run is to empty the transformer field in the attributes and then get the warnings again. They are registered and the entity is new. But when I specify the transformer, the device crashes with "NSLocalizedFailureReason=CloudKit integration requires that the value transformers for transformable attributes are available via +[NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName:], return instances of NSData, and allow reverse transformation:"

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` also (although I don't need secure coding, see below), but I did not have success. Thus I used a custom value transformer instead. My steps were:

I implemented my custom value transformer class:

```
@objc(MyTransformer)
class MyTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func setValueTransformer(_ transformer: ValueTransformer?, forName name: NSValueTransformerName) {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        let data = serialize(value) // A custom function, e.g. using an NSKeyedArchiver
        return data as NSData
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
        let set = deserialize(data) // A custom function, e.g. using an NSKeyedUnarchiver
        return set as NSSet // Or as an NSArray, or whatever the app expects
    }
}

extension NSValueTransformerName {
    static let myTransformerName = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: „MyTransformer")
}
```

The 1st line (`@objc`) is required, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32597074/1987726)! Otherwise coreData does not recognise the custom transformer!

Next, I implemented a computed property in the app delegate, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137593/1987726):

```
private let transformer: Void = {
    MyTransformer.setValueTransformer(MyTransformer(), forName: .myTransformerName)
}()
```

It is important to do this early, e.g. in the app delegate, so that coreData does recognise the transformer when it is initialised.

Eventually, I set in the attribute inspector of the transformable attribute in the `xcdatamodeld` file the Transformer value to `MyTransformer`.

Then the code run correctly without run time logs.
Please note:  In my case, it was not necessary to do secure coding, but the code above can easily be modified to use secure coding instead. Just modify the functions `serialize` and `deserialize` accordingly.

**EDIT** (due to the comment of kas-kad below):

Sorry, my code was unfortunately not complete.

In the app delegate, I used the following computed property (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137593/1987726)). This ensures that the value transformer is registered very early, even before `init` is run.

```
private let transformer : Void = {
    let myTransformer = MyValueTransformer()
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(myTransformer, forName:NSValueTransformerName("MyValueTransformer"))
}()
```

And to `override class func setValueTransformer` does in my implementation obviously nothing. I copied it from somewhere (cannot remember). So one can surely omit it.

The extension of `NSValueTransformerName` does nothing more than to allow to use `.myTransformerName` as the transformer name.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Although I'm wondering, if you've given up on adopting `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` for your transformable properties, and you don't require secure coding, why not explicitly use `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` instead? This should silence the error, no?

Comment: Probably yes. I didn't try it. I tried to follow Apple's advice to set as transformer `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`, which did not work. In my answer, I showed a way to implement a custom transformer that can be implemented insecure or secure, as required.

Comment: I've come up with the similar solution (preferring using custom insecure transformers compatible with good old default transformations). But my implementation misses `setValueTransformer` overriding, as well as extension part `static let myTransformerName =  ` and app delegate part. Everything works fine, the model successfully recognizes the transformers that I specified in the property fields in the attribute inspector. Could you elaborate the need of those changes that I miss?

Comment: @kas-kad Thanks for your comment! My implementation above is unfortunately not complete, and overriding class func setValueTransformer is unnecessary. Please see my edit above. Thanks for letting me know!